# How view error on VPS Debian for odoo module

Tags: debian, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I'm install odoo 9 on debian, after copy custom module from my VMware and try install module can't install only stay "Cancel install".

How view error, why module can't install. On VMware work fine.

Comment: see odoo logs under /var/log/ directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try find this path

```
/var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
```